# How to get youtube id from url , input submit

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to get youtube id from urls

```
https://youtu.be/id
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=id
```

My code:

```html
<form action="http://www.example.com/">
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone guide me on how to get this result?

```
http://www.example.com/id
```

[image: Explanation]

Comment: where you want to get it ? with JS,PHP ? be more precise please

Comment: @TemaniAfif The question is tagged with [tag:javascript] so OP likely wants a JavaScript solution

Comment: with javascript . html static page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var uri = document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value;
  var id = /youtu.+(\/|=)(.+)$/.exec(uri)[2];
  alert('http://example.com/'+id);
}
```

I don't know what to say more. If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: Nice code THANKS Mr Joshua K

Answer (score 0):

Check out my simple solution

```
var url = 'https://www.youtu.be/watch?v=98123712638'; 
var parsedStr = url.split("v=")[1];
parsedStr = (parsedStr != undefined) ? parsedStr : url.split("youtu.be/")[1];
var resultId = parsedStr.split("&")[0];

console.log(resultId);
```